# Как сменить статус поста после редактирования на Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, post

Все новые посты пользователя получают статус ***"На утверждении"*** и их должен опубликовать администратор. Но, после того, как запись опубликована, пользователь можно спокойно ее изменить.

Как сделать так, чтобы после редактирования запись опять была ***"На утверждении"***?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Повесьте хук на событие `"save_post"`, проверяйте роль редактирующего запись (здесь есть хорошая таблица соответствий прав пользователей их ролям http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities). Если пользователь ниже ранга редактора и запись имеет статус "опубликовано", меняйте статус записи на `"pending"` ("на утверждении").

```
function my_func_on_save_post($post_id) {
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
        return $post_id;
    }
    if (!current_user_can('edit_pages', $post_id) && get_post_status($post_id) == 'publish') {
        wp_update_post(array(
            'ID' => $post_id,
            'post_status' => 'pending'
        ));
    }
}
add_action('save_post', 'my_func_on_save_post');
```

Comment: Спасибо! Проверил - все отлично работает)

Answer (score 0):

В админке, в редактировании записи, в правом сайдбаре (в самом верху), есть окошко "Опубликовать". В нём "Статус". Укажите там "На утверждении" и сохраните.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это да, но мне надо, чтобы этот статус ставился автоматически, чтобы пользователи не могли сами публиковать контент на сайте без премодерации

Comment: А вы какой то плагин используете?

Comment: Для чего плагин? Пока выставил в админке, чтобы всем посты от авторов уходили в "на утверждение", изменил роль авторам чуть-чуть.

Лучше бы решить вопрос без плагина, конечно...

Comment: Проверьте свой вопрос. Я так понял: обычные пользователи сайта могут сами создавать записи, не входя в админку. А вы хотите что бы эти записи не опубликовывались автоматически, а стояли на утверждении, так?

Comment: Это уже реализовано стандартными средствами wordpress. (Входя в админку)

Comment: Мне надо, чтобы, если пользователь отредактирует свою запись, которую опубликовал админ она опять ушла с сайта.

Comment: Я думал речь идёт об обычных пользователях, не залогиных на сайте. Я не встречался с данной ситуацией.